# How to address someone like the owner of a guesthouse

Tags: grammar, words, politeness, second-person-pronouns

So I am currently in Japan for vacation and also some short work visit and had the chance to use Japanese a little. I learnt things mostly from reading, so I struggled to formulate things verbally in spontaneous conversation. I can speak enough to go for shopping and restaurants using just Japanese, but not good enough for long casual chats (I can understand but cannot formulate replies well).

One thing that came to mind was this: I wanted to ask (1) "How should I address you?" and (2) "should I call you the owner (of the guesthouse)?"

I know sometimes we do not need to use things like 「あなた」, but is 「あなた」the right word for "you" when speaking to the owner of a guesthouse I am staying?

For (1), presumably that's more like asking for name, so I thought it's not quite right --- is 「なんてお呼び良ければいいんでしょうか」 correct?

For (2), my first guess was 「大家さんと呼ぶのはいいんでしょうか」, is this fine or what's the refinement?

Comment: Saying something like（何を／どう）すればいい**の**でしょうか？ in real life conversation often sounds like you are perplexed or annoyed. You should say 〜すればいいでしょうか？ without の if you want to simply ask a question.

Comment: 大家 (landlord) isn't right unless you are 店子 (tenant).